# Multiple Select not working, only giving last clicked value

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I implemented a multiple select dropdown from [react-bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/).

It does not let me do multiple select and only gets the last clicked option. I have state variable set to array. What else am I missing? App is created with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

I have state set to array inside the class constructor. Binding of event handler also done in the constructor.

Next, I'm showing my event handler followed by form group with `onChange` and value set to state. (note I have a drop-down above this which is working fine.)

I then pass this value to a few classes before it's parsed to JSON. The last pastes are those classes. I have removed other parameters so easier to read, any ideas, feel free to ask for more info.

```
this.state = {

 codeCoverage: [],

}

 this.handleCodeCoverageChange = this.handleCodeCoverageChange.bind(this);
```

```
//Event handlers below
    handleCodeCoverageChange(event){
        this.setState({
            codeCoverage: event.target.value
        })
    }
```

```
<Form.Group>
<Form.Label>Please choose your desired code coverage software(s)</Form.Label>
<Form.Control as="select" value={this.state.codeCoverage} onChange={this.handleCodeCoverageChange} multiple>
<option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
<option value="cobertura">Cobertura</option>
<option value="sonarcube">Sonarcube</option>
</Form.Control>
</Form.Group>
```

```
var configurator = new Configurator(this.state.codeCoverage)
```

```
class Configurator
{
    constructor(
        code_coverage)
    {
        this.pipeline = new Pipeline(code_coverage)
    }

}
```

```
class Pipeline
{
    constructor(code_coverage)
    {
        this.analysisAndSecurity = new AnalysisAndSecurity(code_coverage)
    }
```

```
class AnalysisAndSecurity{
 parameter
    constructor(code_coverage)
    {
        this.code_coverage = code_coverage

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your handleChange function you assign `state.codeCoverage` the value of the selected element instead of `adding` it to the array of selected element. This is why when you select another element it deletes the old value. I would recommend logging `e.target.value` and `this.state.codeCoverage` to better understand. As for the solution:

Since you are using `multiple select` it expects an array as value instead of a single value. So you need to change two things in your `handleChange` method.

1. First you need to `add` your element to existing values and not replace them.
2. You need to handle when a selected element is clicked again and needs to become unselected.

You can do both these tasks as shown below:

```
handleChange = e => {
  const { codeCoverage } = this.state;

  // Find the value selected the codeCoverage array
  const index = codeCoverage.indexOf(e.target.value);

  // If the value is not found then add it to the array
  if (index === -1) codeCoverage.push(e.target.value);
  // If value found then remove the value to unselect
  else codeCoverage.splice(index, 1);

  // Set the state so that the component reloads with the new value
  this.setState({ codeCoverage: [...codeCoverage] });
};
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you Hussain, up vote for you ;)